# Как добавить комментарий в документ с разметкой Markdown?

Tags: разметка, комментарии, markdown

Нужно добавить в документ на Markdown комментарии, которые бы не экспортировались в итоговый документ.

Есть стандартный html-комментарий:

```
<!-- comment text -->
```

Проблема в том, что при экспорте такой комментарий попадает в итоговый документ в неизменном виде. Можно ли сделать такие комментарии, которые будут вырезаться при экспорте в HTML?

Comment: А зачем это надо?

Comment: @Qwertiy: например, я пишу документацию. Исходники в Markdown, результат собирается в PDF или HTML. Я не хочу, чтобы конечные пользователи видели мои комментарии.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это реализуемо с помощью ярлыка ссылки (link label), с которым не связывается ни одна ссылка. 
Эти ярлыки ссылок будут вырезаны при экспорте:

```
(пустая строка)
[comment]: # (comment text)

(пустая строка)
[//]: # (comment text)
```

Сравните с обычным синтаксисом ссылки:

```
[link text][label]

[label]: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

В принципе, спецификация Markdown допускает вариант, когда перед комментарием нет пустой строки, а вместо `#` используется `<>`. Проблема в том, что спецификация дырява как решето, а имеющиеся 28+ реализаций работают по–разному. Добро пожаловать в Markdown!

Проверить работу различных реализаций нам поможет инструментарий Babelmark2, проверяющий рендеринг разметки Markdown в различных реализациях. (`+` — прошли тест, `-` — не прошли, `?` — оставляют неотображаемый мусор в HTML).

- [Без пустых строк, с `<>`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=Braces%20and%20no%20empty%20lines%3A%0A[comment]%3A%20%3C%3E%20%28THIS%20SHOULD%20BE%20REMOVED%29%0Asome%20other%20text) 13+, 15-
- [Пустая строка перед, с `<>`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=Braces%20and%20an%20empty%20line%20before%20the%20comment%3A%0A%0A[comment]%3A%20%3C%3E%20%28THIS%20SHOULD%20BE%20REMOVED%29%0Asome%20other%20text) 20+, 8-
- [Пустая строка перед и после, c `<>`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=Without%20empty%20lines%20around%20comments%3A%0AUsing%20braces%3A%0A%0A[comment]%3A%20%3C%3E%20%28THIS%20SHOULD%20BE%20REMOVED%29%0A%0Asome%20other%20text) 20+, 8-
- [Без пустых строк, с `#`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=Without%20empty%20lines%20around%20comments%3A%0AUsing%20braces%3A%0A%0A[comment]%3A%20%3C%3E%20%28THIS%20SHOULD%20BE%20REMOVED%29%0Asome%20other%20text) 13+ 1? 14-
- [Пустая строка перед, с `#`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=Hash%20and%20an%20empty%20line%20before%20the%20comment%3A%0A%0A[comment]%3A%20%23%20%28THIS%20SHOULD%20BE%20REMOVED%29%0Asome%20other%20text) 23+ 1? 4-
- [Пустая строка перед и после, c `#`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=Hash%20and%20empty%20lines%20around%20the%20comment%3A%0A%0A[comment]%3A%20%23%20%28THIS%20SHOULD%20BE%20REMOVED%29%0A%0Asome%20other%20text) 23+ 1? 4-

Согласно проверке, наиболее платформо-независимый вариант — это `#` и пустая строка перед комментарием. Пустая строка после комментария не играет роли. В частности, набирающая популярность строгая **спецификация [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/)**, в разработке которой участвует Jeff Atwood, **работает именно с этим вариантом** (и не работает с `<>` и/или без пустой строки)

C этими реализациями нет никакой возможности использовать такие комментарии:

- cebe/markdown 1.1.0
- cebe/markdown MarkdownExtra 1.1.0
- cebe/markdown GFM 1.1.0
- s9e\TextFormatter (Fatdown/PHP)

Исследование основано на решении, предложенном [участником Magnus на SO.EN.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885980/2790048)